# Compiling PHP with GD and libjpeg support

Tags: php, centos, unix, gd

I compile my own PHP, partly to learn more about how PHP is put together, and partly because I'm always finding I need modules that aren't available by default, and this way I have control over that.

My problem is that I can't get JPEG support in PHP. Using CentOS 5.6. Here are my configuration options when compiling [PHP 5.3.8](http://uk2.php.net/get/php-5.3.8.tar.gz/from/a/mirror):

```
 './configure'  '--enable-fpm' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--with-gd' '--with-curl' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-zlib' '--with-pear' '--with-gmp' '--with-xsl' '--enable-zip' '--disable-fileinfo' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/'
```

The `./configure` output says:

```
checking for GD support... yes
checking for the location of libjpeg... no
checking for the location of libpng... no
checking for the location of libXpm... no
```

And then we can see that GD is installed, but that JPEG support isn't there:

```
# php -r 'print_r(gd_info());'
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] =>
    [T1Lib Support] =>
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] =>
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] =>
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] =>
)
```

I know that PHP needs to be able to find libjpeg, and it obviously can't find a version it's happy with. I would have thought `/usr/lib/libjpeg.so` or `/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62` would be what it needs, but I supplied it with the correct lib directory (`--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/`) and it doesn't pick them up so I guess they can't be the right versions.

`rpm` says libjpeg is installed. Should I `yum remove` and reinstall it, and all it's dependent packages? Might that fix the problem?

Here's a paste bin with a collection of hopefully useful system information:
http://pastebin.com/ied0kPR6

Comment: If I use `--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/` it outputs a rather more promising `checking for the location of libjpeg... /usr/local/lib/`. But then it still doesn't list JPEG support in the output of `php -r 'print_r(gd_info());'`.

Comment: Try it wih `--with-jpeg-dir=/usr`. I think autoconf looks in `lib/` within the specified directory.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. Similar my above comment, it said `location of libjpeg... /usr` but didn't lead to JPEG support.

Comment: This was the solution. I set `--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/` and now it works! Please post this solution as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: How odd. Perhaps the idea is to distract autoconf by making it look in `usr/local/` whilst quietly slipping the correct lib into its pocket. :) Still, I couldn't possibly accept this answer, since mine was wrong. Feel free to post your own solution and accept it, though, so that other in the same position will find it.

Comment: No your answer was right. I have two versions of libjpeg installed - `yum`'s one in `/usr/lib`, and one I compiled from source in `/usr/local/lib`. It obviously didn't like the first. And I wouldn't have known how to make it look for the second properly without your answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll wrap it up. Curious as to why it doesn't like your distros version of the library, though. Are they different versions?

Comment: @SmallClanger let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1181/discussion-between-robin-winslow-and-smallclanger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set `--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/` and it worked! It appears to add the `lib` itself.

Answer (score 1):

you need libjpeg-devel too if you are COMPILING your own php and extensions

```
yum install libjpeg-devel
```

you need all the -devel equivalents for libraries that you are going to link and use (curl-devel, zlib-devel, gmp-devel, etc)